# Plotly error "WebGL is not supported by your browser"

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to create some 3D plots using `plotly` package.

The code that I am using is their tutorial example

```
library(plotly)
# volcano is a numeric matrix that ships with R
fig <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface()

fig
```

However, I get the following output. I already followed the guideline in https://www.thewindowsclub.com/webgl-is-not-supported-on-chrome-firefox but still did not work. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, is the web browser OS's default ?

Comment: I use Windows and the default browser is Chrome. I also checked for Firefox and IE but didn't work.

Comment: See these instructions:  https://www.interplaylearning.com/help/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome.  The likely reason WebGL is disabled is that your video card has a known bug, so this may make your system less stable.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem but I can still save the plot going to [Export/Save as web page] and then saving as HTML file.

Comment: Why would this happen in one app but not another? I mean webapp.

Comment: https://github.com/statnett/vue-plotly/issues/7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it forcing RStudio to use 'Desktop OpenGL'. In RStudio, I went to **[Tools/Global Options.../Advanced]** and choosing '**Desktop OpenGL**' in Rendering engine.

[image: Changing rendering engine in RStudio]

Source:

- [community.rstudio.com: WebGL is not supported by your browser - Plotly](https://community.rstudio.com/t/webgl-is-not-supported-by-your-browser-plotly/13962/17)
- [Related Plotly GitHub Issue 3573](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3573)

Comment: My R studio stopped opening after this change. Please approach with caution !!

Comment: Same here, if it does break, you'll have to reset the RStudio sate.