# adding a z-axis to a radar chart in R

Tags: r, 3d, radar-chart

I am trying to replicate a human thorax with 12 ribs, utilising a radar chart (ggradar) consisting of 360 data points (see image below).

[image: Radar plot thorax]

Looking for help in adding a z-axis & conversion to a 3-dimension structure where each ring sits on top of eachother.

Appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can do a 3D render using plotly. Bear in mind that with 360 data points over 2 ribs, there is only 30 points per rub layer, making the imagery a bit sparse. See the code below.

```
set.seed(417)

library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

#create fake data
n <- 360

rib_x <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
rib_y <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

#remove section of rib to get the hollow space shown
rib_x <- ifelse(rib_x > quantile(rib_x, 0.95), 0, rib_x)
rib_y <- ifelse(rib_y > quantile(rib_y, 0.95), 0, rib_y)

rib_z <- rep(seq(from = 1, to = 12, length.out = n/12), each = 12)

#plot
plot_ly(x=rib_x, y=rib_y, z=rib_z, type="scatter3d", mode="markers",
        color=rib_z,
        size = 15) %>% layout(title = 'Rib Plot')
```

Increasing your number of data points by a factor of three gives a more granular representation for each rib layer.

As a side note, if the image is not rendering, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61241340/plotly-error-webgl-is-not-supported-by-your-browser) about visualising plotly graphs in R.